# Validation of the JWT Bearer Token payload

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, bearer-token

*tldr*: Do I need to validate a payload from the received token?

So here's the first step with the creating of the token:

```
from jose import jwt

to_encode = {
    "iss": "https://example.com/",
    "aud": "metaserver",
    "sub": user.username,
    "name": user.display_name,
    "metadata": metadata
}
# Here goes the updating of the payload (exp, iat, etc)
...
token = jwt.encode(to_encode, config.JWT_SECRET_KEY, algorithm=algorithm='HS256')
```

The `metadata` field is being saved in the db. It can be anything.

The second step is when I receive a client-request and I have to check the token:

```
decoded = jwt.decode(token, config.JWT_SECRET_KEY, audience='metaserver', algorithms=[config.ALGORITHM])
```

In the [documentation](https://jwt.io/introduction) it is mentioned that:

> What is the JSON Web Token structure? In its compact form, JSON Web
> Tokens consist of three parts separated by dots (.), which are:
>
> Header
> Payload
> Signature
>
> Therefore, a JWT typically looks like the following. xxxxx.yyyyy.zzzzz

So in my case the `Payload` field is my `metadata`

**The question is**: is it possible for the user to send a token with the "old" `Header` and `Signature` parts `(xxxxx.____.zzzzz)` but to include his own `Payload (____.his-own-payload.____)`?
Is it enough for me just to rely on the result of the `jwt.decode`? Do I have to do an additional request to the `db` to compare with the received `metadata`?

Comment: The function `jwt.decode`  verifies the signature. That's why you have to pass the key and algorithm to it.  If you change the payload (or header), signature verification will fail.

Comment: @jps yes, that's what I wanted to be sure in:
"The server adds a signature based on the payload when issuing a token to the client"
so it's secure as well to decode a token on any other separate service just having a private key.